# Is there any profit from using pure and view functions modifiers?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas, remix, evm

I have a function that does not read or modify contract's state:

```
contract C {

    function add(uint a, uint b) public returns (uint) {
        uint res = a + b;
        return res;
    }

}
```

Does it make sense to use pure/view modifier? I mean, will the function use less gas after that or what is the reason to use it?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25200/solidity-what-is-the-difference-between-view-and-constant

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you can make your function `pure`, you should always make it `pure`. Otherwise, if you can make your function `view`, you should always make it `view`.

Advantages:

- If you make your function `pure` or `view`, you can call it for example through web3.js without needing a transaction, without any gas cost and without confirmation delay.
- Currently, it will not reduce gas cost when executing on the EVM. However, in the future it may help the Solidity compiler to optimize your program.
- It will prevent you from accidentally reading or writing contract state in functions where you don't want to.

Disadvantages:

(none)

Comment: It's 2022. Are pure and view functions optimized by Solidity?

Comment: Only the last advantage you have listed makes sense. The first 2 are automatically determined by the solidity compiler.