# What is the purpose of using this; in the end of function

Tags: solidity

I've randomly stumbled upon a code where the function uses this; in the end of function

```
function _preValidatePurchase(address beneficiary, uint256 weiAmount) internal view {
        require(beneficiary != address(0), "Crowdsale: beneficiary is the zero address");
        require(weiAmount != 0, "Crowdsale: weiAmount is 0");
        require(weiAmount >= minPurchase, 'have to send at least: minPurchase');
        require(_contributions[beneficiary].add(weiAmount)<= maxPurchase, 'can\'t buy more than: maxPurchase');
        require((_weiRaised+weiAmount) <= hardCap, 'Hard Cap reached');
        this; //What is the purpose of using this; here
    }
```

In last where **this;** is used what is the purpose of using this, as far as i know **this** keyword refers to current instance but what purpose does it serve there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solidity: Function state mutability warning](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/39562/11746) and thus: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28509/11746 and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28571/11746 (halfway through the answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a way of telling the compiler to silent unwanted warnings. If there wasn't `this` keyword, the compiler would have said `state mutability can be restricted to pure`, which is not necessarily true for the contracts that might override this function and read the state variables.

See for [more](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96810/silence-visibility-warning-state-mutability-can-be-restricted-to-pure):