# Why is balanceOf() marked as constant in ERC-20

Tags: solidity, erc-20

in. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md

it is written:

```
function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance)
```

I understand the usage of the constant modifier in decimals() and name() - but I am having trouble understanding why balanceOf() is constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`constant` in Solidity is not the same as `constant` keyword in other languages.

In Solidity `constant` keyword mean:

- `constant` function should not modify the state (not fully enforced
  yet)
- `constant` state variable (ie. the one in the class and not in a
  method) is evaluated every time it is called

By the way, it might be important to mention that two new function modifiers were added. You can read about them more [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/25202/9938) and [here](https://youfoundron.com/blog/solidity-constant-vs-view-vs-pure/).

Answer (score 0):

It is marked with a keyword "constant" because it does not modify the state. However, contrary to the variables, marking functions with a "constant" keyword doesn't mean it could be executed without the need for the transaction. If you are curious, you can find more information here: [Could we call a constant function without spending any gas inside a transaction function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13851/could-we-call-a-constant-function-without-spending-any-gas-inside-a-transaction/13855)