# Why we need "stateMutability" in contract's ABI if we already have "constant" and "payable"?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, abi

stateMutability: a string with one of the following values: pure (specified to not read blockchain state), view (specified to not modify the blockchain state), nonpayable and payable (same as payable above).

constant: true if function is specified to never modify blockchain state;
payable: true if function accepts ether, defaults to false.

Comment: Within the original design some use cases were not possible to express. For example a pure function doesn't have an equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`constant` has been deprecated in favour of `pure` and `view` - [see here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25200/solidity-what-is-the-difference-between-view-and-constant)

`pure` is used for functions where state isn't even read (e.g. safeMath type functions) whereas `view` is used for functions which don't change state but do read from it.

in terms of the ABI, `constant` was retained for backward compatibility:

> Remarks:
>
> JSON ABI has a new field statemutability introduced with a string value as above
>
> JSON ABI keeps constant/payable for backwards compatibility for a while

Source: [Axic's comment on 15 Aug 2017 here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/992)

Comment: I guess the OP is not interested in the difference between pure/view/constants etc. He is asking why the abi contains `stateMutability` term since view/constant are already defined in the function signature.

Comment: The answer is clear. `constant` and `payable` was retained for backward compatibility. Thank you!